# Socket IO requires node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

For using Socket IO, node js is necessary? if not, Can someone give an example code?

Comment: http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/writing-socket-io-application-that-runs-on-the-jvm/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, node.js is needed for the server side... From the [Github readme](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io#readme):

> Socket.IO is a **Node.JS project** that makes WebSockets and realtime possible in all browsers.

See [the Github page](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) or the [website](http://socket.io/) for more information and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily - you need a websocket server, this can be [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) or a `java` `websocket` server - http://jwebsocket.org/ or even a `.NET` `websocket` server - http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

If you want a `nodejs` websocket server/client example - http://goo.gl/b7ncb

Answer (score 0):

implementations of socket.io-server on other languages:

- java: [Netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio)
- python: [python-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio)
- golang:

  - https://github.com/graarh/golang-socketio
  - https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io